# How do I set priorities quartz triggers in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I use Quartz scheduler with cron expressions for few tasks to be executed on a regular intervals in my `Java Spring MVC` application. In my `root-context.xml` file, I have the following:

```
<!--Quartz Scheduler Beans   -->

    <bean id="emailNotificationJob" 
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="targetObject" ref="eventsService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="sendEventEmailNotification" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />    <!-- this is the property to prevent concurrent execution -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="deleteWebContentsJob" 
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="targetObject" ref="webContentDefinitionService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="deleteWebContents" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />    
    </bean>


    <bean id="saveStaticContentsJob" 
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="targetObject" ref="webContentDefinitionService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="saveStaticContents" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />    
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailTrigger" 
                class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="emailNotificationJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *" />

    </bean> 

    <bean id="deleteWebContentsTrigger" 
                class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="deleteWebContentsJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 1 0 1/1 * ? *" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="staticContentsUploadTrigger" 
                class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="saveStaticContentsJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *" />

    </bean> 

    <!-- Scheduler factory bean to glue together jobDetails and triggers to Configure Quartz Scheduler -->
    <bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="emailNotificationJob" />
                <ref bean="deleteWebContentsJob" />
                <ref bean="saveStaticContentsJob" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="emailTrigger" />
                <ref bean="deleteWebContentsTrigger" />
                 <ref bean="staticContentsUploadTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Quartz Bean End -->
```

I use `Quartz Scheduler 2.2.1` in my application.

I want to set priorities for various triggers. Here I have two triggers that are set to fire at same time intervals. I am trying to set one of them as priority 1 and the other one as priority 2. Is there a way to do that.

Comment: see quartz docs for [Trigger Priorities](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example14.html)

Answer (score 1):

`CronTriggerFactoryBean` has a property called `priority` (spring-context-support:4.2.4.RELEASE). This is in turn used to set the priority of the `CronTriggerImpl`, which has a [javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/triggers/AbstractTrigger.html#setPriority(int)) that states:

> The priority of a Trigger acts as a tie breaker such that if two Triggers have the same scheduled fire time, then Quartz will do its best to give the one with the higher priority first access to a worker thread.
>
> If not explicitly set, the default value is 5.

Then again, if there are enough threads in the thread pool for both processes, I'm not sure if the priority will have any effect (depending on whether the priority is also assigned to the actual worker thread).